# Process data that is being sent to stdout

Tags: swift

I'm calling an `AVFoundation` method that is logging **a lot** of data to `stdout` and there's no option to turn this logging off.

Is it possible to write something like a middleware to process the data **before** sending it to `stdout`?

Something like this pseudocode:

```
Process.beforePrint( data => {
   if (data !== blackListedData) {
      print(data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options you can employ using the `stdio` functions. Here's a simple one that redirects stdout to a log file:

```
class StdoutFilter {
    let path: String = {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        return (paths[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("swift.log")
    }()

    func startFilter() {
        freopen(path, "w", stdout)
    }

    func stopFilter() {
        fclose(stdout)
    }
}
```

You can use this trivial implementation like this:

```
let filter = StdoutFilter()

print("This goes to stdout…")

filter.startFilter()

print("This gets logged to the file…")
print("Put your AVFoundation stuff here.")

filter.stopFilter()

print("And we're back to normal!")
```

This could be modified in a few obvious ways. You could redirect the output to `/dev/null`, for example. You could also try monitoring the file and applying a predicate to determine whether the filter should be started or stopped, but I think that's more complex than I have time for at the moment.

One final note: `"w"` in the `startFilter()` function will overwrite the file if it exists. Use `"a"` if you prefer to append an existing file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aaron! I didn't understand how would I do the filtering :( I need redirect to `/dev/null` every line that contains `LevelIDC`. Otherwise, I want it to be on the logged normally.

Comment: @Matheus I think you could take an approach like this: (1) call `startFilter()` to a log file, (2) make another function that constantly reads the file, (3) if the file has a new line not containing `LevelIDC` then call `stopFilter()`, print it again, then call `startFilter()` again